# Why is Universal Generalization a necessary rule, if "for ALL" is already the definition of ∀?

Tags: predicate-logic

I am just learning about **Universal Generalization** and don't understand why it is even brought up. There is nothing to prove in "∀xP(x) is true, given the premise that P(c) is true for all elements c in the domain", the ∀ already *literally* says that the proposition is valid **for all** elements. I could accept it as a "definition", fine, but how is this a "rule"???

To me that sounds just like, "For all means for all! Bam, proof!" - and I'm so done with this ---

Comment: That isn’t really what universal generalization says. An informal version of what it actually says is that if we can prove $P(x)$ without assuming anything about $x$ beyond the fact that it’s in the domain of discourse, then we can conclude $\forall x\,P(x)$. You can see the actual formal statement of universal generalization [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_generalization).

Comment: Universal generalization is the rule corresponding to the "*arbitrary element*" technique in mathematical arguments: to show that $\forall xP(x)$ is true, we **introduce an "arbitrary" object $c$**, show that $P$ holds of $c$, and **then conclude** that $P$ in fact holds of every element since $c$ was arbitrary. *(In the context of formal proof, we want precise rules which let us build "valid sequents" (or similar), and natural-language proof strategies need to be reflected by such rules (or combinations thereof). Based on your last couple sentences, I think this may be a point of confusion.)*

Comment: Your argument applies to **all** the rules of first-order logic: they are all "obviously" correct, in some sense. However, that does not make logic uninteresting, because what logic is trying to do is to model our reasoning processes in a rigorous way that avoids appealing to any intuitions about the meaning of symbols. In saying you are "done"with mathematical logic, you are giving up on a lot o interesting ideas, both mathematical and philosophical.

Comment: First of all, thanks for all your comments (I can't upvote yet)! 
Just to make it clear, I am seriously confused by this and am indeed trying to understand it - not throwing in the towel yet. I think my main concern is that I cannot think of any sensible **definition** of ∀ (and it has to be defined first, right?) that does not already explicitly include being true for arbitrary elements, making this a somewhat **circular reasoning** without any value added.  
I can - to a degree - enjoy the art of first-order logic, this is the first time I really fail to see the point.